# Displaying a value obtained from a mysql query into a VB.net textbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, count, textbox

I am trying to display a value I obatain from a COUNT(*) query in a textbox in vb.net but instead of displaying the obtained value it displays the actual query.

Here is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Statistics
Dim conn As MySqlConnection
Dim command As MySqlCommand
Dim query As String
Dim dadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;database=librarydatabase"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader


    Try
        conn.Open()
        query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login where users='" & Username.Text & "'"


        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        dadapter.SelectCommand = command
        If reader.HasRows Then
            reader.Read()
            takenout.Text = (query)


        End If

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of my program: [image: link]

When trying to fix the code I change it to replace takenout.Text = (query) with takenout.Text = (reader.read()) and deleting the reader.read()) above and dadapter.SelectCommand = command

Here is the changed code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Statistics
Dim conn As MySqlConnection
Dim command As MySqlCommand
Dim query As String
Dim dadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;database=librarydatabase"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        conn.Open()
        query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login where users='" & Username.Text & "'"


        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader


        If reader.HasRows() Then

            takenout.Text = (reader.Read())


        End If

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

This code doesn't fix the problem but instead displays true in the textbox when the button is pressed no matter whats in the username textbox.

Here is an image of that: [image: link]

Comment: Rather than blindly trying random code, you should spend 10 mins at MSDN to see how the [DBDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) works.  Once you `Read()` a row, you need to fetch the data.  But for a `Count()` query that can only return one row, you dont need a reader, `command.ExecuteScalar()` will return the value

Answer (score 1):

Use `command.ExecuteScalar()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using command.executescalar() fixes the issue.

Here is a copy of the fixed code if anyone else has a similar issue and wants to see a working example.

```
Public Class Statistics
Dim conn As MySqlConnection
Dim command As MySqlCommand
Dim query As String
Dim dadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;database=librarydatabase"
    Dim numtakenout As String

    Try
        conn.Open()
        query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login where users='" & Username.Text & "'"


        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)


        numtakenout = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar())


        takenout.Text = numtakenout




        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```